# PHP: Accessing outer static variables

Tags: php

Class `A` has a member with a function:

```
class A {
    public function foo() {
        static $x=2;
        function bar() {
            echo "x=$x";
        }
        bar();
    }
}
$a = new A();
$a->foo();
```

This gives an error in line `echo "x=$x";`.

How to access `$x` from class member `foo()` in function `bar()`?

I'm using PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `self::$x`?

Comment: No, that results in ```FATAL ERROR Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active...```. ```$x``` is no static class member!

Comment: `$x` is out of scope for `bar()`. There's several options, [here's](https://3v4l.org/m2saA) one of them.

Comment: Ok, works. Isn't there a direct way to access ```$x```?

Comment: Define "direct". They're different scopes.

Comment: No because you're actually defining `bar()` as a standard function in the global scope.... just because you're defining it within a method doesn't change that

Comment: Direct means e.g. by scope operator. As here with ```global```: http://php.net/manual/de/language.variables.scope.php#98811
But that's an ugly solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution, based on the closure idea of @ishegg:

```
class A {
    public function foo() {
        static $x=2;
        $bar = function () use (&$x,&$bar) {
            echo "x=$x\n";
            if (++$x<6) $bar();
        };
        $bar();
    }
}
$a = new A();
$a->foo();
```

This recursion is possible because the closure is passed to itself as reference. And since a reference is just a pointer it can be evaluated before the function is fully defined. So the solution effectively relies on closures passed by reference.

Please note that `$x` has also be passed to as reference `&$x` since otherwise we just get a copy of `$x` and the static variable `$x` never changes.

Runs like a charm: https://3v4l.org/U293s

Result:

```
x=2 
x=3 
x=4 
x=5
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to declare your static variables within a function.

```
class A {
    protected static $x = 2;

    public function foo() {
        function bar() {
            echo "x=" . self::$x;
        }

        bar();
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo();
```

Comment: Given context it is hard to say if this is the right answer or not. But I would imagine that this scenario (static class property) is more likely what OP wanted to use.

Comment: Why not declare static variables inside functions?

Comment: A solution: http://php.net/manual/de/language.variables.scope.php#98811 
But a bad one!

Comment: This doesn't work. `bar()` is in the global scope, it can't see `$x`: `Fatal error:  Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trello/up.php on line 8`

Comment: I also thought of using the ```use``` keyword for function ```bar()```: ```function bar() use ($x) { ...```. But use is only available for closures :-(
Do we have to wait for a future PHP release?

Comment: @ishegg is right - this doesn't work (don't know who upvoted it), although it's not in *global* scope (try calling `bar()` from outside the class, it's undefined), it's not in class scope either. It's in `foo` 's function scope.

Comment: @WeSee: Defining named functions within functions hardly serves any purpose - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In my program ```$x``` is a large array which I want to search using a quick search algorithm ```bar()```. And thus ```bar()``` needs to access ```$x```.

Comment: Why not just perform the search in `foo()` directly..? Or use another private (or public, if this is useful in your context) class method?

Comment: @ishegg: Good idea to use a closure! I'll give that a try.

Comment: Wouldn't call it a *good idea*, I'm just spitting stuff that works. That doesn't make it right :).

Comment: @ishegg: Sorry, I cannot use a closure here because I need to call ```bar()```.recursively. AFAIK this is not possible for closures.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit/ask a question about your underlying problem (class array, sorting), creating a minimal example etc.